# Invalid geo coordinates when searching for venues

Tags: coordinates, foursquare

when searching for venues (intent "browse", southwest and northeast provided) I receive the following error:

> Invalid geo coordinates (0.400000,0.000000)

What's wrong with these coordinates? I thought latitude is supposed to be in the range -90 to +90 and longitude in the range -180 to +180 ...

Any help is appreciated! Thanks, Carl

Comment: It's likely rejecting the coordinates because they're in the middle of the [Gulf of Guinea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Guinea).

Comment: I wouldn't think so, I tried the nearby {0.41,0.01} and {0.401,0.001} successfully.

Comment: Okay, then I guess I don't know what your question is.

Comment: I played around with the values a bit (thank you, apigee.com) - seems like the 4SQ API does not accept all-zero values (0.0), neither for latitude nor longitude. Any idea why?

Comment: Likely because it uses a parser that internally returns zero to indicate an invalid entry. So it rejects a perfectly-valid zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior. The vast majority of cases where people send us 0.00 as a lat/long coordinate, it's because of some programming error/mistake, with an uninitialized variable, for example.

So, we return an error, so it's easier to find the mistake, rather than silently returning little-to-no results. If you send 0.00001, it will be treated as perfectly valid, and refer to essentially the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Since [your coordinates](http://maps.google.com/?q=0.400000,0.000000) are even not assigned to a country, this coordinates are not valid. Try using coordinates on dry land.