# Where can I post bugs in the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

I found a strange behaviour in the 4SQ API: [Invalid geo coordinates when searching for venues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10297569/1353618)

Where can I post this bug to let the 4SQ team know about it?

Comment: Some team members are on stackoverflow. I am sure that they will correct the behavior when they think you discovered a (serious) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack overflow is the best place to report issues. Foursquare considers it our "Developer Forum."