# Zero latitude/longitude not allowed in Foursquare searches?

Tags: coordinates, foursquare

The 4SQ API does not accept all-zero values (like 0, 0.0, 0.00) for latitude or longitude when searching for venues (intent "browse", southwest and northeast provided). I always receive the following error:

> Invalid geo coordinates

Is this is a bug or intended behaviour? Do zero values have some special meaning so they cannot be used as lat/long parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behavior -- we added this feature because the overwhelming majority of requests to (0,0) are due to some programming mistake, that we think the developer would like to know about. So, instead of silently returning no and/or bogus results, we return an error to help developers debug.

Fortunately, 0,0 is out over the ocean without much going on around there. You can always try 0.01,-0.01 if you want to make a request about that part of the world...

Answer (score 1):

David Schwartz said something about it on this post : [Invalid Geo Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297569/invalid-geo-coordinates-when-searching-for-venues)

> Likely because it uses a parser that internally returns zero to
>   indicate an invalid entry. So it rejects a perfectly-valid zero

Maybe you should think about it.

Comment: I already did, but was hoping that maybe someone from 4SQ could confirm David's assumption. That's why I created a separate "bug report" here.